# Защита JS файлов от подбора по ссылке

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, безопасность

Есть директория в проекте, она имеет такую структуру js/admin/admin.js
Ссылку на файл простой юзер никогда не получит, эти JS файлы подключаются только когда подгружается шаблон для админа. Но вот если например обычный юзер будет просто угадывать ссылки, то посмотреть эти JS файлы он может, прописав в сроке браузера http://domen.test/js/admin/admin.js . Я бы не хотел ему показывать содержимое этих файлов, потому что он может извлечь кое какую информацию о структуре проекта. Хотя на сервере все проверяется, но все же.

Подскажите, можно ли как то с помощью файла .htaccess настроить доступ так, что бы по ссылке в браузере ему ничего не показывало, но при загрузке страницы да.

Скорее всего что нельзя, и борюсь с этим я называя файлы в стиле admin_4ку3п3.js
Но поскольку я перфекционист это меня раздражает, подскажите какими вариантами можно решить этот вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте запаролить директорию через htaccess https://www.google.com/search?q=htaccess+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8E&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8 Дополнительная защита для админки.

Comment: @Visman да но тогда скорее всего эти JS не будут подгружаться и при загрузке шаблона

Comment: Думаю вас попросит браузер ввести пароль при доступе к директории. Предлагаю протестировать. Если не устраивает, то отдавайте этот файл через движок сайта (только админу). Файл в таком случае реально не надо держать в этой директории.

Comment: @Visman мне вот советуют JS код вынести в шаблон, это был бы норм вариант если бы его было там не много.

Comment: Второй вариант, это почти как в шаблон. Третий вариант, если имеете статический ip адрес, то через .htaccess разрешите доступ к файлу только с него.

Comment: Вариант с выносом кода JS в шаблон самый простой. Если Вас беспокоит объем самого кода и потеря наглядности, тогда просто вынесете файл admin.js выше document_root и подгружайте в шаблон с помощью include.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю что за шаблон здесь предлагается, но не проще ли использовать UglifyJS?